# テーブルからカラムの値を取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

今、映画紹介サイトをつくっています。
スクレイピングでタイトル、映画の画像、監督、公開日などなど映画の情報をとあるサイトから取得しました。もうすでにMySQLにはtitileカラム、imageカラム、directorカラムなどなどにデータが入っています。

タイトルを映画の画像に一致させたいです。
productsテーブルに映画の画像が入っていて、いまWEBサイトにはその画像が表示されています。
そしてそのタイトルと一致させたいのですがうまくできません。
NoMethodError in ProductsController#index
undefined method `order' for　　とエラーが出ました。

products_controller.rbに

```
class ProductsController < RankingController
  def index
    @products=Product.new(@title).order('id DESC').limit(20)←ここが大事
    @title=Product.select("title")
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.new
 end
end
```

@products変数を定義したときのnew(@title)が間違っているのかなと思いますが、どのようにここの部分を記述すれば良いのかわかりません。

Comment: この質問に限らないのですが、コードを書くに当たって参考書やドキュメントは参照されていますか。明らかに記述がおかしいです。 市販の書籍や http://railstutorial.jp などでRubyとRailsの基礎から勉強された方が良いように思います。

Answer (score 1):

`Product.new(@title)`が何をしたいのか理解できませんでした。
適当に20件取得して並び替えなら以下のコードで行けると思います。

```
@products = Product.limit(20).order('id DESC')
```

この辺りのリファレンスをよく読んで組み合わせてください。
http://railsdoc.com/references/where
http://railsdoc.com/references/order
http://railsdoc.com/references/limit